# How to split multiple files into a gb folder?

Tags: windows-7, split

I am downloading many folders and then splitting them into 1 Gb folder in windows OS. Right now, it is a manual process. Is there any windows command/program to split all the files into 1Gb folder?

Answer (score 1):

You have the command [`split`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?split)

```
split -b1G your_filename part
```